# Crear un update a partir de un if o un case en sql o postgresql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Estoy haciendo un programa de inventario para un proyecto con RFID el problema es tener controladas las entradas y salidas.

Cuando sale algo del almacen, no es necesariamente que salga permanentemente por lo que puede volver a entrar, el problema es que las salidas y entradas son detectadas por los sensores, la tabla de esta parte la tengo de la siguiente manera.

Numero_Caja | Fecha_Entrada | Fecha_salida | Existencia

En el cual el numero de caja es la llave primaria y existencia es booleana cuando entra una caja nueva se agrega el numero mas fecha de entrada y cuando esta misma caja entra se agrega la fecha de salida y la existencia cambia a false, como la caja puede volver a entrar quiero que de la tabla se borre la fecha de salida y el estado de existencia cambie a true si este vuelve a entrar, y para eliminar de la tabla las cajas que ya no volvieron a entrar se agrego un boton que eliminara todos los que en exitencia esten en false.

Ya definido el contexto llevo tiempo intentando que al volver a entrar cambie el estado de la existencia y si esta vuelve a salir se vuelva a cambiar tengo una pequeña aproximacion con lo siguiente :

```
UPDATE market 
SET exitdate = CASE WHEN existence = true AND boxnumm = caja que lee el sensor then now() else null END,
    existence = CASE WHEN exitdate <> now() AND boxnumm = caja que lee el sensor then false else true END
;
```

pero de igual manera funciona a medias puesto que se tiene que ejecutar 2 veces para que funcione y funciona de mala manera puesto que cambia el estado y la fecha de la caja actual pero los de los demas los regresa a true y con la fecha en null.

Si le les ocurre otra manera como pasar el dato de la existencia a una variable en el programa tambien me serviria de ayuda.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No has puesto ni una coma ni un punto! ;) Entiende que redactar la pregunta correctamente es una parte importante para que todos te entendamos, frases como  _para que cambie el estado del cambio_ sin conocer el modelo son difíciles de comprender para alguien que leemos tu casuística por primera vez. Intenta mejorar tu post por favor.

Comment: Ya mejore el post como dices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pero no tendrías que ejecutarlo dos veces. Efectivamente la comparación con el número de caja que lee el sensor debería estar en la cláusula `WHERE` para seleccionar el registro a actualizar.

En el `UPDATE` deberías actualizar los 3 campos en función de si el campo `existence` está establecido como `true` o `false`.

Si `existence` es `true` se trata de una salida y por tanto la fecha de entrada se deja tal como está, la fecha de salida se establece con la fecha actual y `existence` pasa a `false`.

Si `existence` es `false` se trata de una entrada y por tanto la fecha de entrada se establece con la fecha actual, la fecha de salida a `NULL` y `existence` pasa a `true`

```
UPDATE market
SET entryDate = CASE WHEN existence THEN entryDate ELSE NOW() END,
    exitDate = CASE WHEN existence THEN NOW() ELSE NULL END,
    existence = CASE WHEN existence THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END
WHERE boxnum = caja que lee el sensor
```

Comment: No se me ocurrio de esa manera pero tienes razon el existence es el boolean que necesito, lo estoy probando y funciona solo para si alguien se topa con esto va un end al terminar cada sentencia gracias aun no se mucho de como funciona stackoverflow pero gracias no se me hubiese ocurrido esa solucion

Comment: Cierto. Lo corrijo.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione no se si sea lo mas correcto pero esta funcionando con lo siguiente

```
UPDATE market 
SET exitdate = CASE WHEN existence = true AND boxnumm = xxxx then now() else null END,
    existence = CASE WHEN exitdate <> null AND boxnumm = xxxx then false else true END
    WHERE boxnumm = xxx
;
```

lo unico que lo tengo que ejecutar dos veces y ya hace lo que queria